# XText can not insert line before current quickfix point (XText version 2.9)

Tags: xtext, cross-reference

### In my Xtext project I want to use quickfix to insert a new line before the current line for the missing cross-reference.But it gives following exception.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2015-06-02 17:22:05.616
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Select and reveal referenced object".
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The feature 'content' is not a valid feature
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.BasicEObjectImpl.eStructuralFeature(BasicEObjectImpl.java:733)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.BasicEObjectImpl.eObjectForURIFragmentSegment(BasicEObjectImpl.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.getEObject(ResourceImpl.java:766)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.getEObject(ResourceImpl.java:742)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.resource.XtextResource.access$1(XtextResource.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.resource.XtextResource$1.getEObject(XtextResource.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.resource.DefaultFragmentProvider.getEObject(DefaultFragmentProvider.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.resource.XtextResource.basicGetEObject(XtextResource.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.resource.XtextResource.getEObject(XtextResource.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.linking.lazy.LazyLinkingResource.getEObject(LazyLinkingResource.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.LanguageSpecificURIEditorOpener.findEObjectByURI(LanguageSpecificURIEditorOpener.java:159)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.LanguageSpecificURIEditorOpener$2.process(LanguageSpecificURIEditorOpener.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.LanguageSpecificURIEditorOpener$2.process(LanguageSpecificURIEditorOpener.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.util.concurrent.IUnitOfWork$Void.exec(IUnitOfWork.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.resource.OutdatedStateManager.exec(OutdatedStateManager.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.model.XtextDocument$XtextDocumentLocker.internalReadOnly(XtextDocument.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.model.XtextDocument$XtextDocumentLocker.readOnly(XtextDocument.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.model.XtextDocument.readOnly(XtextDocument.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.LanguageSpecificURIEditorOpener.selectAndReveal(LanguageSpecificURIEditorOpener.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.LanguageSpecificURIEditorOpener$1.run(LanguageSpecificURIEditorOpener.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

---

**My Code is very simple liking this:**

```
    acceptor.accept(issue, "Create label", "Create a new jump label", null) [ element, context |
                if (element instanceof ContinueCommand) {
                    var lineNum = issue.lineNumber
                    var doc = context.xtextDocument
                     // If use doc.getLineOffset(lineNum). It works and inserts newline after current line.
                    var offset = doc.getLineOffset(lineNum-1)
                    var id = doc.get(issue.offset, issue.length)
                    var toInsert = "!" + id + " : comment\n"
                    doc.replace(offset, 0, toInsert)
                }
            ]
```

I tried it in other quickfix methods (not for cross-references). It works good. I use xtext version 2.9.

Has anybody the same problem?

Comment: Please file a ticket against Xtext - this looks like a bug to me.

Comment: I have the same problem. The thing is that Xtext is trying to select code (part of your AST in code editor)  defined by URI and fragment. For example: return.ctl#//@ed.0/@cs/@sb/@sod.0/@e/@e/@feature/@operand but when the quick-fix is applied and the code is changed (one line is added before the statement you want to fix), the original part of code is here: return.ctl#//@ed.0/@cs/@sb/@sod.1 (NOTICE THE 1 INSTEAD OF 0)/@e/@e/@feature/@operand, but Xtext is trying to select the old element on index 0 (which is now something else than it was before) and so it crashes.
btw: I have Xtext 2.8.3

Comment: [link](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=472467)